# VBA: trying to return an array but only getting the first value

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I think this question has been asked a thousand times but after hours of searching I still can't find any help. So I need to use a vector of numbers as an input, do a calculation to all of those numbers and then return the results as a vector with a same dimension as the input vector. So lets say that I want to take some numbers and then subtract all of them by one and so my Excel sheet should look like this

```
    A   B
1   6   5
2   7   6
3   8   7
4   9   8 
5   10  9
```

where column A is the input vector and B should be the output. But my output is only a column of zeros. Debugging also tells that the right numbers are there in the output vector but I can only print the first value which then goes to all cells. At the moment my code looks like this

```
Public Function Vector(values As Range) As Variant

    Dim arraySize As Integer, i As Integer
    arraySize = values.rows.Count
    Dim returnArray() As Variant
    ReDim returnArray(arraySize)

    For i = 1 To arraySize
        returnArray(i - 1) = values(i, 1) - 1
    Next i

    Vector = returnArray

End Function
```

Comment: When debugging, does the line `Vector = returnArray` give you what you're expecting, i.e. `Vector` is an array of values?

Comment: Can you add the code you're using to write the array to the sheet?

Comment: It looks like your issue at the moment is that you're mostly using a 1D array. Also what is the range "values"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a **2-dimensional** array:

```
Public Function Vector(values As Range) As Variant

    Dim arraySize As Integer, i As Integer
    arraySize = values.Rows.Count
    Dim returnArray() As Variant
    ReDim returnArray(1 To arraySize, 1 To 1)

    For i = 1 To arraySize
        returnArray(i, 1) = values(i, 1) - 1
    Next i

    Vector = returnArray

End Function
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

When entering the array formula in the worksheet, hi-light cells **B1** through **B5**, then click in the Formula Bar and then enter the formula with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function Vector(values As Range) As Variant

    Dim r As Long, c As Long, returnArray As Variant

    returnArray = values.Value

    For r = 1 To ubound(returnArray, 1)
    For c = 1 To ubound(returnArray, 2)
        returnArray(r, c) = returnArray(r, c) - 1
    Next c
    Next r

    Vector = returnArray

End Function
```